# Java library to split text into smaller files

Tags: java

I am looking for a java library that allows me to specify max size or max number of lines in output files, and then splits a large xml/text file into smaller files.

I saw that there is a 2 year old question on SO for the same, however the answers there were for specific cloud platforms....I just want a library for use in java desktop apps.

Comment: if you split an XML document, the fragments won't be well formed though.

Comment: Are there any rules? (eg: do the resulting XML files have to be valid XML? Can plaintext files split on words? Sentences?)

Comment: well i thought that initially i will split the single file into multiple ones, then add some fixed text at beginning and end of all split files (so that properly started and ended elements are there in all split xml files)...if you have a better idea then kindly let me know...

Comment: That won't work though if you split based on number of lines or characters because you could be splitting an XML element. There would not be a way to have some default header or footer that would handle this.

Comment: You might be able to parse the XML and only output a limited number of elements per file but you wouldn't know the size of each element.

Comment: well the xml i want to parse has one single group element per file, so the header and footer needed in each file is the same, so even if there is a library to split files, i can split the files and then put same header/footer in all files...

Comment: Why are you worried about the size of the actual files? Why not keep your files in-tact and read them in chunks?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Guava [CountingOutputStream](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html) to keep track of how much data is written to a file. Write one line at a time, check the number of bytes written and once you exceed the threshold close the file and open a new one.